# Set and transfer royalties for a NFT

Tags: nft, metadata, transfer, mint, fee

How to set royalty while minting a NFT. If I set creators in metadata how can I transfer royalties when someone buys this NFT?

This is my Minting code:

```
pub fn mint_nft(
    ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
    creator_key: Pubkey,
    name: String,
    symbol: String,
    uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("Nft token minting:");
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    let result = mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1);
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MintError::MintFailed));
    }
    msg!("Token minted !!!");

    msg!("Metadata account creating:");
    let accounts = vec![
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];
    let creators = vec![
        mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {         
            address: creator_key,
            verified: false,
            share: 100,
        },
        mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
            address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            verified: false,
            share: 0,
        },
    ];
    let result = invoke(
        &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            name,
            symbol,
            uri,
            Some(creators),
            1,
            true,
            false,
            None,
            None,
        ),
        &accounts
    );
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MintError::MetadataCreateFailed));
    }
    msg!("Metadata account created !!!");
    Ok(())
}




#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintNFT<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_authority: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub rent: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

and this is the buy NFT code:

```
pub fn fill_order(ctx: Context<FillOrder>) -> Result<()> {
    let order = &mut ctx.accounts.order;
    let buyer = &mut ctx.accounts.buyer;
    let creator = &mut ctx.accounts.creator;

    //
    // Check buyer's balance against order's price.
    //
    if buyer.lamports() < order.price {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::InsufficientMoney));
    }

    //
    // Transfer order's money from buyer into creator.
    //
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
            &buyer.to_account_info().key(),
            &creator.to_account_info().key(),
            order.price
        ),
        &[
            buyer.to_account_info(),
            creator.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info()
        ]
    )?;

    //
    // Transfer order token account's token into buyer token account.
    //
    let seeds = &[
        b"order",
        ctx.accounts.mint_key.key.as_ref(),
        &[order.bump]
    ];
    let signer = &[&seeds[..]];
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.order_token_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.order.to_account_info()
    };
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);
    let result = transfer(cpi_context, 1);
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::TokenTransferFailed3));
    }

    //
    // Close order token account.
    //
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_accounts = CloseAccount {
        account: ctx.accounts.order_token_account.to_account_info(),
        destination: ctx.accounts.creator.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.order.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);
    let result = close_account(cpi_context);
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::TokenCloseFailed));
    }

    Ok(())
}



pub struct FillOrder<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"order",
            mint_key.key.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        has_one = creator,
        close = creator
    )]
    pub order: Account<'info, Order>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = order.mint_key,
        associated_token::authority = order,
    )]
    pub order_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    pub mint_key: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint=buyer_token_account.owner == buyer.key(),
        constraint=buyer_token_account.mint == mint_key.key(),
    )]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

Comment: This is done by modifying the exchange process at a low level. If you share your repository I would gladly help you

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code for NFT minting and buying. Kindly take a look and help me execute royalty distribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult for me to work without having the repository, I cannot give you a specific answer. So broadly speaking I can recommend you use this method:

```
fn to_f64(amount: u64) -> f64 {return amount as f64}
    fn percent(amount: f64) -> u64 {((amount / 100.0)* 2.0).round() as u64}  
    let owners_amount = percent(to_f64(AccountInfo::lamports(&account.to_account_info()) - 70254250));
    let owners_dividend: u64 = owners_amount / 8; 
    let winner_reward: u64 = AccountInfo::lamports(&solotery.to_account_info()) - 70254250 - owners_amount; 
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner1.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner2.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner3.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner4.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner5.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner6.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.owner7.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= owners_dividend;
    **ctx.accounts.creator.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += owners_dividend;
    **account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= winner_reward;
    **winner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += winner_reward;
```

Comment: <https://github.com/LoboVH/check-unicus/blob/main/programs/unicus_ts/src/lib.rs> this is the link to the contrract repository. Please take a look. Thank you.